# How to store molecule data using SMILES when building a toy chemistry model

Tags: modeling

I'm currently building a toy chemistry model based around `Gillespie's algorithm`. Starting from a food set of `{H,O,N,C}` I let my system evolve, I have been storing my molecules as strings in SMILES format.

For instance:

```
[O] reacts with [H] --> [O] ([H])

[O] ([H]) reacts with [H] --> [O] ([H]) ([H])
```

Using square brackets I've been able to keep the molecules in my system consistent with their SMILES interpretation.

However this system of storage is only allowing me to construct linear molecules.

How can I create, for instance, a carbon ring, so that it is interpreted in SMILES as only a ring of carbon atoms, without hydrogen atoms?

For instance C1CCCCC1 gives http://www.chemicalize.org/structure/#!mol=C1CCCCC1&source=calculate How would I generate 6 carbon atoms in a ring without the 12 hydrogen?

Comment: Links to helpful pages for other curious people : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system

Based on reading those two entries, it sounds like you just want [C]1[C][C][C][C][C]1 ?

Comment: @Mikeb Thank you for this, definitely a step in the right direction, except it appears this doesn't generate a hydrogen complete molecule, see http://www.chemexper.com/

Comment: @Mikeb Wait a momment, i'm very sorry! http://www.chemicalize.org/structure/#!mol=%5BC%5D1%5BC%5D%5BC%5D%5BC%5D%5BC%5D%5BC%5D1&source=calculate